# Basics on Matlab function Unique

Tags: matlab, unique

I'm studying the function `unique`, which looks simple at a first sight but I don't understand some properties.

I created a matrix `A` and tried to analyze the outputs:

```
A=[5 2 4 5;
   1 1 3 4;
   6 1 2 3]

[C0,IA0,IC0]=unique(A)

[Cr,IAr,ICr]=unique(A,'rows')

[Cf,IAf,ICf]=unique(A,'first')
```

1. In `C0` the logic of the output is *"create a vector in which there are values that appears at least one time"*

   But I don't know the meaning of `IA0` and `IC0`. I just know the relation that `C=A(IA0)` and `A=C(IC0)`. Are these 2 output created only to satisfy this two relation? So why should I be intersted in their outputs?
2. In `Cr` ('rows' example) the logic of the output is *"give me back the rows of the original matrix `A` but sorted ascending. Also, if you find at least two or more rows that repeat with same values and order, show that row only once in `Cr` output"*

   The logic of `IAr` is very intuitive: *"give me back the index that must follow the `Cr` output to order the rows."* So in my example gives me back a vector like `IAr=[2;1;3]`. Thus the second row of the original matrix `A` must be the first in the `Cr` output, the first row in `A` matrix must be the second in `Cr`...

   But I still don't understand the output `ICr`
3. In `Cf` ('first' example) gives me back the same output as `C0`. And it's not really clear to me how to use properly this function.

---

Can anyone gives me a simple explanation about how this function works?

Are there any simple practical examples in which I can take advantage of these other outputs?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: yes i did, but it's explained in general.

Comment: Your question asks for a general explanation.

Comment: no, clearly it doesn't. I'm asking for a specific explanation of the outputs, because the general intuition gives me no useful information.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, you could start learning how not to be childish

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Matlab is a generic tool. So asking "why" some functions give extra output just because it *might* be useful to someone for some reason is difficult to answer.

1. `IA0` gives the indices of the last elements that might have been chosen by `unique`. `IC0` contains indices to replicate `A` using only the unique elements. Why do they exist? You may not only be interested in unique values, but also where to find them in `A`.
2. You are misinterpreting how `rows` works. It simply treats the rows of your matrix as atomic and returns the unique rows. To get a better idea of how it works, run `A(3,:) = A(2,:)` before calling `unique`. Then the idea behind `IA0` and `IC0` is the same as in the previous case, except now with rows.
3. The `first` option only changes how Matlab chooses the indices of `IA0`. Again, the reason behind this is that Matlab is a generic tool. You might be interested in finding the latest repeated occurence of each value or in the first. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question and the answer are being downvoted. The author said he read the documentation, yet he didn't fully understand it. The question is clear and I'm explaining as objectively as possible. If you have something to contribute, just drop a comment.

Comment: I down voted because: "What is an integer, I read documentation and did not understand it" is the same type of question. There is only one real answer: read it again, but this time slower. Do you think that any (including yours) explanation of exactly what MATLAB documentation has (which is great, and includes examples) is better than the MATLAB explanation?

Comment: i guarantee you AnderBiguri that i red paying attention the ML explanation. BTW i'm not the only one with doubts about unique function in ML. Anyway too much noise for nothing, if you have used the same effort to try to solve my question that you used to downgrade it, I would have solved my doubt pretty soon (But could you do that?). Anyway, Thank You @giusti that was really helpful! But referring always to IA0=[2;4;8;7;1;3] i still don't get where those number came from.. What does 2 mean? What does 4 mean? and so on

Comment: @Carlo this shoudl also be a learning experience of what types of questions are OK in StackOverlfow and which ones are not. Hopefully with my effort in this questions you will learn how to write better questions in the future and everyone will save time and effort.

Comment: They are indices of `A`. The key point is that when you used a single integer to index a matrix, it is treated as a long array from the concatenation of the columns. So `A(1)` is row 1, column 1, `A(2)` is row 2, column 1, and so on. If you do `B = A(:)` then the values in  `IA0` will be very clear from the indices in `B`.

Comment: @giusti ok Thank You